# Is there a way not to show line breaks using the "more" command in windows cmd displaying an image file as text?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ico

I have an ".ico" file and I need to show it in the cmd as text using the more command. The problem is that while using the "type" command I get the right output showing all the characters like that:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test vari\box prova>type imageres_30.ico
```

```
♦Ç♦ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ└└└           wwwwçpwwwwww♠▬pwwwwww°pxwwêêÅxç↨wÇvxêÅ°êÅ°vwê°°°°Å⌂ °pwêÅ ÅÅ°°⌂⌂  çpÅÅÅ°° °⌂⌂°°°pÅÅ°  ê°Å⌂ ÅÅÇÅÅ ÅÅ °⌂⌂ÅÅêÇÅÅÅ°°°°Å⌂°êÅpÅÅ Å Å°⌂ÅÅÅêÇÅÅÅ Å°°Å⌂êêêpÅÅ Å Å°⌂⌂êêêpÅÅ  Å °Å⌂êêêpÅÅ°  Å°⌂êêêxpÅÅ ° °°Å⌂xçêpÅÅ  ° °⌂⌂êxêpÅÅ°   °ÅêxçêpÅÅ  Å°°⌂xçêxpÅÅ    °ÅêxxêpÅÅ    °⌂xêçêpÅÅ ° Å°⌂êxxxpÅÅ    °ÅxêêxÇÅÅ    °⌂êxxêpÅÅ °  °êêxçêpÅÅ c⌂ °ÅxçêxpÅÅ°8wêêêêêxxpÅ°°x¿°êÅêxçêpÅ  çÅÅÅÅêxxêpÅÅ  °ÅÅÅ⌂xçêpêêêê    êêêxpÅ    ÅÅÅêxx°Ç   °êêêçêêçwê°êêççêxêÅêp☼Çêêxêxêê                          ■     Ó?   ■☼   ­   ♥  ■   ⌂  Ç?  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  ⌂  Ç⌂  õ    ´                                 ( ☻ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ└└└            wwpçwwG7wwgx°pppxÅ⌂Åçx°  ⌂⌂ Ç° ÅÅ⌂ÅÅ°°Å° ⌂ÅÅÅ°° ÅÅ⌂êÅ° Å ⌂Åêêp☼°Å Å⌂êêê° Å ÅÅêê°  Å⌂êçê°°  ⌂êêxÇ☼°   Åêxê° ° ⌂êçê°°  ⌂êêx°   êêxx°   ⌂Åxêp☼°°( Åêçê°¸wê⌂êêx°xxêÅêxxÇ☼Å  ÅÅêêê°ÅÅêÅêêêpêêêêçêêçÇêçxxçêê             ­?  ☼ ° °♥ ³☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °☺ °
```

and so on....

using the "more" command the output is shown like that:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test vari\box prova>more imageres_30.ico


☺

00►
☺
♦
h♠

Í


  ►
☺
♦
Þ☻

>

↑↑►
☺
♦
Þ☺

&


►►►
☺
-- More (0%) --
```

but I need it to be shown like the first output. I cannot use the "type", I can only use the "more" (anyway if there are other similar command any suggestion will be appreciated)

Comment: I'm curious why you could not use `type`? What about `copy /b imageres_30.ico con: >nul`?

Comment: It is unclear the benefit of displaying a binary file as text. If you want to see what is inside the binary file, you might use `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command Format-Hex -Path '.\imageres_30.ico'`.

Comment: `more` is competely different from `type` . You can read about both usage by adding the `/?` switch to each command, but as @Stephan clearly requested, what is the reason you cannot use type when you have demonstrated yourself that type gives the output you want?

Comment: @Stephan I'm working on alternate data streams as system to hide informations. The goal is to save an image into ads of a file and then frome there, copy the image to a new directory. The problem is that the "type" command can be used to save a file into the stream, but it's unable tu read files from there. same thing as "copy, xcopy and robocopy etc". It seems that the only one that can handle this is the "more" command. so the script would be sth like that: "more < file:icon.ico > newfileinnewdirectory.ico". But it is only possible if the more command can output the text in the right format

Comment: @Gerhard read the comment I wrote to @ Stephan

Comment: @Andre you can not handle a binary file with MSDOS because there are many things in question like characteres non readable, charset, control characters, string split, the own reading that the commands make... Then exporting this will always come out with errors. However, you would need a binary file editor or hex converter.  But what you asked in the question was to see it on the screen, and that's what I gave you. Then please consider accepting the answer by clicking ✓ on the left. Note that you get 2 reputation points accepting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is impossible if you believe in your inner Priapus

```
FOR /F %s in ('more /C /S your.ico ^| findstr /v /R "[&>]"') do @(ECHO|SET /p dummyVar=%s) 2>nul
```

Explanation:
`FOR /F %s` run the command inside `('...')`
and then execute the `@(...)` for each row returned.
`^| findstr /v` escape pipe and execute a filter before send the result out.
The `/v /R "[&>]"` cuts off each row that does not have & or > in Regular Expression, 
thus preventing the file's content thrown on the screen to execute commands or write new files by coincidence, such as #@$%`&`$#%`>`@$#%¨@ `fileContent&execute>writeFile`.
And finally `ECHO|SET /p dummyVar=%s` is a trick to give `ECHO` with no line breaks, where the `%s` is the line returned.